# Encode Custom Data Type to Lazy Byte String

Tags: haskell

when you want to convert a custom type into bytestring you would do following:

```
data Foo = Foo {value1 :: Int}
instance Binary Foo where
   get =liftM Foo get
   put b = put (value1 b)
```

and if you have a type with multiple viable values as such:

```
data Foo2 = Foo2A Int | Foo2B Int 
instance Binary Foo2 where
   get = do flag <- getWord8
         case flag of 
               0 -> fmap Foo2A get
               1 -> fmap Foo2B get
   put (Foo2A i) = do put (0 :: Word8) 
                      put i
   put (Foo2B i) = do put (1 :: Word8)
                      put i
```

but if you have a type as such (following...) how would I do this?:

```
data Foo3 = Foo3A Int | Foo3B
instance Binary Foo3 where
   get = do flag <- getWord8
            case flag of
                 0 -> fmap Foo3A get
                 1 -> ....????? Foo3B has no value - only Data Constructor
   put (Foo3A i) = do put (0 :: Word8)
                      put i
   put (Foo3B)   = put (1 :: Word8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also derive these instances:

```hs
newtype Foo = Foo {value1 :: Int}
  deriving newtype Binary

data Foo2 = Foo2A Int | Foo2B Int
  deriving stock Generic
  deriving anyclass Binary

data Foo3 = Foo3A Int | Foo3B
   deriving stock Generic
   deriving anyclass Binary
```

Comment: with this example the result of (decode . encode) Foo3B is emtpy (=() ) for me

Comment: @ThomasMeyer That's because you called `decode` at the wrong type. Try adding a type signature.

Answer (score 1):

To match what you wrote for `put`, you want `pure Foo3B` there in `get`.